# Unable to install Windows 7/8 on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I am running a Debian-based linux OS called CrunchBang. I am trying to install Windows 7 or 8 (doesn't matter) on VirtualBox. However when I get to the installation phase sometimes copying files doesn't move, it doesn't even give me a percentage. Other times "installing files" stays at 0% for hours.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Edit: I am using an .ISO file saved in my /home directory
Its a legit copy as well.

Comment: More information is required. Are you sure the installation media   being used actually works?

Comment: A way to test that the ISO is valid is to burn it and see if you can boot from it. If your download source offered an MD5 you can check that for integrity as well.